# Named URLs for React app

Tags: create-react-app

Does Create-React-App support named URLs e.g. my-app.dev as opposed to the default localhost:3000?
I am using a Windows 10 machine. I used to use an Apache virtual host to set this up but I can't figure out how to do it in CRA.

UPDATE:
I've half solved the problem by adding `127.0.0.1 www.my-app.dev my-app.dev` to the hosts file located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.
I also had to create a `.env` file in the root of my React project and added `HOST = my-app.dev`
I then tried to add `PORT = 0` to the `.env` file but that made no difference.
Now when I run the app with `npm start` it opens at `my-app.dev:3000`
Is there a way to get rid of of the port?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer on the CRA Github page [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1959#issuecomment-292929203)